# CSS Snap Scroll, vertical scroll issue

Tags: css, scroll

Hey guys in dire need of help with an issue I've spent hours at this point trying to solve.

Dealing with a very custom html, css design with lot's to consider. I'm afraid something is preventing CSS snap scroll to work properly and I can't figure out why.

Here is my code, I'm using bootstrap 4.

**HTML**:

```
<body>
 <main>

  <div class="container padding-top">

   <div class="snap-scroll-container">

    <section class="section snap-scroll-child">
     <div class="project-link-container">
      <img src="example">
     
     <h1 class="title">Testing</h1>
     </div>
    </section>

   </div>

  </div>

 </main>
</body>
```

**CSS**:

```
body {
        height: 100vh !important;
    }

main {
        has no styling;
    }

padding-top {
        padding-top: 100px;
   }

.snap-scroll-container {
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    }

.snap-scroll-child {
        scroll-snap-align: center;
    }

.section {
        position: relative;
        height: 390px;
        width: 690px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

.project-link-container {
       has no styling
    }

.section img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 390px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

.title {
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: 900;
        line-height: 0.9em;
        top: 45%;
        right: -38%;
        width: 700px;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        transition: 500ms;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

Any help at all is appretiated.

Ian

Comment: It looks like you are overriding the snap-styles of `.snap-scroll-child` with relative positioning in the `.section` class (very confusing name for a class btw)

Answer (score 1):

Try yo add a height value in your .snap-scroll-container